# incon class java iin eclipse is different

Tags: java, eclipse, java-10, javacompiler

I have two class .java but in pdcController.java I cannot do anything:

Look the image:
[image]

Look the icon are different in BandoService works all, but in .pdfController I cannot do anything (for example I cannot suggest for method or error import). pdfController and BandoServiceare in the same project.

Comment: `PDFController.java` is not in a source folder (or, less likely, in a source folder but excluded as a source file) and will therefore not be compiled.

Answer (score -1):

This is not the source file, check the file path, you're probably not in the correct package.
I guess you have several modules in your maven project and you opened the file from the parent module.
If you see the file only in the parent module it's time to git fetch.